# Python: unexpected token

Tags: python, lambda

```
min(gameinfo.not_my_planets.values(), key=lambda p: p if p.num_ships < 35)
```

Trying to get the minimum planet but only while there are planets that have 35 or less ships.

get unexpected token ')' though any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `else` part in lambda expression, but you better Rewrite it to:

```
min(filter(lambda p: p.num_ships < 35, gameinfo.not_my_planets.values()))
```

`filer(...)` will reduce the sequence of planets to those having `num_ships < 35`. Are `planet` objects comparable among them selves or should you compare to an attribute planet, 
`planet.size`? If so, you have to add another lambda:

```
min(filter(lambda p: p.num_ships < 35, gameinfo.not_my_planets.values()), key=lambda p:p.size)
```

If you are **not used to functional constructs**, just use simple list comprehension (I assumed planets are comparable among them selves):

```
min( p for p in gameinfo.not_my_planets.values() if p.num_ships < 35)
```

Comment: Its comparable among themselves

Comment: -1 "you can't use `if` in a lambda expression" - you most certainly can use the ternary expression `a if b else c`.

Comment: adding another lambda worked perfectly. I am not to familiar with functional constructs but will mess around with them now :)

Comment: @George Veron I suggest you  to use the last sentence. It's the cleanest one.

Comment: the last one doesn't seem to achieve the right results... and on some play throughs the second one gives me a... min() no args error or similar like its empty so im guessing that's where the else comes in

Comment: @GeorgeVeron it will give that error if there are no planets with under 35 ships. The clearest, though perhaps not the most efficient, way around that is to guard it with `if any(p.num_ships < 35 for p in gameinfo.not_my_planets.values()):`. Or, of course, catch the `TypeError` and handle it.

Comment: If planets are comparable you don't need `lambda p:p.size`. Lambda must allways return a value, so your original lambda could be: p if p.numships < 35 else 99999. 99999 must be bigger than any planet's size. Anyway, it is more clean to filter out unwanted planets and than do the comparisson.

Comment: thanks that works what does any() do precisely though never used it before and not use to all this pythonic stuff

Comment: also just tested out catching typerrror, seems like a much better option might do it later when i extend the project

Comment: @GeorgeVeron - `any(x)` just returns True if any of the elements of x evaluates to True, otherwise returns False.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the point of that lambda even is...  Going by what you said you want in a comment to another answer:

To "select planets with 35 or more ships":

```
planets_35_or_higher = [p for p in gameinfo.not_my_planets.values() 
                        if p.num_ships >= 35])
```

To "select minimum of the rest":

```
planets_below_35 = [p for p in gameinfo.not_my_planets.values() 
                    if p.num_ships < 35])
min_planet_below_35 = min(planets_below_35)
```

Or, if planet objects don't have a comparison operator, give the `min` a function to get the attribute it should use for comparison, like this:

```
min_planet_below_35 = min(planets_below_35, key=lambda p: p.num_ships)
```

Also, to deal with the possibility that there are no planets with under 35 ships:

```
if planets_below_35:
    min_planet_below_35 = min(planets_below_35)
else:
    # do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

`p if p.num_ships < 35` on its own is invalid syntax. What should the lambda return if `p.num_ships >= 35`? You need to complete it with an `else`; e.g. `p is p.num_ships < 35 else ...`. The point in the `key` argument for `min` is to select a value for each element by which the minimum element should be determined.

What do you mean by "only while there are planets that have 35 ships or less"? Do you mean you don't want a minimum planet at all if all planets have more than 35 ships?

Comment: i want it to select planets with 35 or more ships (the lowest in that range) then once done (else) select minimum of the rest